# How is TimeBuffer property used in RetryPolicy object in Azure Service Bus client?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

I have read the documentation and all details about how RetryPolicy object is used in Azure Service Bus Queue Client are clear to me, except one: TimeBuffer property. 
Definition in the documentation says:

> "The termination time buffer associated with the retry. Retry attempts
>   will be abandoned if the remaining time is less than TimeBuffer."

But, what is the "remaining time"? Can someone give an example of how is this used?

Here is how I see the situation: If the request fails and error is transient, operation will be repeated until success or until MaxRetryCount is reached. In the meantime intervals between attempts will grow depending on MinimalBackoff and DeltaBackoff until MaximumBackoff reached. From that point, intervals between attempts will be constant and equal to MaximumBackoff. How is TimeBuffer used in this scenario?

One more thing I forgot, so, I edited the question. How to set DeltaBackoff and TimeBuffer when only constructor that allows setting those values is obsolete, and DeltaBackoff property has no setter and is readonly?

Answer (score 0):

TerminationTimeBuffer is a property that is used to limit the total time for the operation to complete.

The termination time buffer associated with the retry. Retry attempts will be abandoned if the remaining time is less than TimeBuffer.

Consider a scenario with following configurations

```
MinimumBackoff = 0  
MaximumBackoff = 30 sec  
DeltaBackoff = 300 msec  
TimeBuffer = 300 msec   
MaxRetryCount = 2
```

It works as

```
Attempt 1: Delay 0 sec   
Attempt 2: Delay ~300 msec  
Attempt 3: Delay ~900 msec
```

Here the "remaining time" after the 2nd attempt would be 29.7 sec and 29.1 sec after the 3rd attempt.

Comment: According to my understanding this is not quite correct. In your example you consider MaximumBackoff as total time. I think MaximumBackoff is maximum time between attempts. Lets use your example and say that MaximumBackoff is 600ms. Then I think attempt 1 and 2 will be as in your example, but attempt 3 and any subsequent attempt will be after 600ms since that is the MaximumBackoff. But, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: When the MaximumBackOff is set to 600ms, attempt 3 and any subsequent attempt will be abandoned as the remaining time is less than TimeBuffer

Comment: I think I undestand what are you trying to say, just your example is not good. In your example TimeBuffer is 300ms. According to that and MaxRetryCount, 3rd attempt will never be executed and remaining time you calculated in the example can not be 29.7 sec because TimeBuffer is not the 30s. I think you mixed MaximumBackoff and TimeBuffer.